# Hibernate Criteria ordering and pagination not working

Tags: hibernate, sorting, pagination, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I see a weird behavior when using `criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("sortAttribute"))` for sorting on **non-unique** attribute. The results returned are duplicate.

The same seems to **work fine** when the sortAttribute is a **unique key** in database.

```
resultObj = criteria.addOrder(order)
                        .setFirstResult(page.getPageNumber() * page.getPageSize())
                        .setMaxResults(page.getPageSize())
                        .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
                        .list();
```

Also, I do have a join here between two entities. (Although I don't really see why this could be any reason for the unstable behavior)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I found a solution to this issue. I did the following to obtain expected results:

- First sort on **non unique key**.
- Then sort on **unique key**.

This way the result was always in the proper order and ordering and pagination was ensured.

Hope this may help someone who comes across such an issue.